# Unicode escape sequence

Tags: c#, mysql, json, unicode, phpmyadmin

I transfered data from a JSON Source to a MySQL database. Some data sets cotain the following string "\u0001". When I look in phpmyadmin this string gets translated in the corresponding unicode character. Is it possible to change the data so that it gets not translated or is there some option to turn off translation?

Comment: that is basically only a interpretation, and it shows clearyöl that the data are correctly saved

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `\u` thingies in PHP:

```
json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use C# for the conversion.